# Mark points on regression line PGFplots

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am to teach, how to do linear regression, and to do so I am making my slides in beamer and I am using PGFplots to do the linear regression, i.e.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
  \begin{axis}
  \addplot[only marks] table[x=Lat,y=Mort]{skincancer.txt};
  \addplot[dashed] table[x=Lat,y={create col/linear regression={y=Mort}}]{skincancer.txt};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Where skincancer.txt is just some textfile containing some data which is somewhat linear dependent.

What I am interested in doing is to mark 2 points on the regression line, in order to remind the students how to find the parameters (alpha and beta) for the linear regression line `y = \alpha x+\beta`.

EDIT: The goal is to not manually enter any values. All values should be grabbed from the dataset that I import. Though it is okay that I have to specify that it is the ith and n-ith points that I am interested in.

Comment: Something like `\draw (axis cs:x,y) circle(5mm);` replacing x and y with the coordinates?

Comment: Well yes, but the coordinates are unknown to me. They are something PGFplots have calculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coefficients are available in `\pgfplotstableregressiona` and `\pgfplotstableregressionb`, so you can just add a second plot with only markers and samples at specific x-values. I took the example below from the manual, and edited it slightly.

To get the x-values from row i and j of the data table, you can do something like in the code below. I don't know if this is particularly fast, but it seems to work.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread{
X Y
1 1.1
2 1.8
3 3.5
4 6
5 4.9
6 7
}\mydata

\begin{document}

% Preamble: \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.14}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend pos=outer north east]
\addplot +[only marks,mark=x] table[x=X,y=Y] {\mydata};
\addplot [red] table[
y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}] {\mydata};

% plot dots on the regression line
\addplot [
   only marks,
   mark=*] table[
   y expr={\pgfplotstableregressiona*
            ifthenelse( % \coordindex starts counting from 0
                  \coordindex==1,% row i-1
                  \thisrow{X}, % X-value from row i-1
                   ifthenelse(\coordindex==4, % row j-1
                         \thisrow{X}, % X-value from row j-1
                         nan)) % if other row numbers, use nan
            + \pgfplotstableregressionb},
   ]
 {\mydata};

%\xdef\slope{\pgfplotstableregressiona} %<-- might be handy occasionally
\addlegendentry{$y(x)$}
\addlegendentry{%
$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x
\pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are there any to get the x coordinates directly from the dataset? like asking for the 3rd and 5th to last points?

Comment: @NickyMattsson Ehm, probably. Maybe you can do it with `\pgfplotstablegetelem` (from `pgfplotstable`).  I don't have time to figure it out at the moment though, maybe later today.

Comment: @NickyMattsson I updated my answer to read the  second and fifth x-value from the table. Change the values after `\coordindex==` to choose the row numbers.